# XML API Integration

Tags: xml, api, magento

I'm currently doing a Hotel booking Website  . So i have a website made using content management system Magento. I want to integrate it with an XML API  . They have provided me with the full manual things to integrate.But doesn't explain how to do this. it contains web methods and its XML. But i don't understand where to put these code and how.
    I just googled and found from stack overflow:

```
 "note.xml"
      <currencies>
     <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
         <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />

      </currencies>
solution
Using DomDocument

<?php
$str = <<<XML
<currencies>
    <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
    <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />
</currencies>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($str);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('currency') as $currency)
{
    echo $currency->getAttribute('name'), "\n";
    echo $currency->getAttribute('code_alpha'), "\n";
    echo $currency->getAttribute('code_numeric'), "\n";
    echo "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+\n";
}
?>

Using simplexml:

<?php
$str = <<<XML
<currencies>
    <currency name="US dollar" code_alpha="USD" code_numeric="840" />
    <currency name="Euro" code_alpha="EUR" code_numeric="978" />
</currencies>
XML; 
$currencies = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach($currencies as $currency)
{
    echo $currency['name'], "\n";
    echo $currency['code_alpha'], "\n";
    echo $currency['code_numeric'], "\n";
    echo "+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+\n";
}
?>
```

But i don't understand on where and how to write this.The processes to do this.
    Can someone provide me with links to do this or any detailed notes available    on internet to do this.
    How can i do it? 
    What are the technical related things(coding), i should know to do this?

Comment: I can point you in the right direction for integrating with Magento's native API but could you please tell me the specific outcome / result you're trying to achieve with the above code?

Comment: Above code is just a sample code i got from stack overflow on how i can convert code from xml document to  php or any other code(not sure). So i just wanted to know how to do xml api integration  (step by step details) if i have an xml document and a magento website.Any links to websites that give details of this would also be appreciable.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial offers a basic, "Hello World" approach to creating your own API endpoint - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785

For further reading, there's always the official Magento 1.x API pages (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) and for *really* deep understanding, Alan Storm's article (http://alanstorm.com/magento_api_soap_adapaters_and_handlers)

It looks as if your endpoint will provide the available currencies with no parameters provided by the user, but that is speculation on my part. Good luck.